# linq query to include but negate the owner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query that looks like this:

```
IQueryable<Incident> listUnpaged = db.Incidents.OrderByDescending(d => d.IncidentDate);
listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => s.User.UserName == user);
listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => !s.PostPrivate);
```

This is a query to show incidents by a specific user and not show them if they are marked private. The `PostPrivate` allows the user to define whether the incident is private or not and therefore not show it in the main list of incidents if it is private. This works.

However, it also doesn't show the incident if the person requesting is the owner. So, for the last line, I need to do something like:

```
listUnpaged.Where(s => !s.PostPrivate //but only where the requestor (userId) is not the owner of the incident (s.UserId))
```

Hopefully that makes sense?

I tried this:

```
listUnpaged.Where(s => !s.PostPrivate).Where(t => s.UserId != userId);
```

But, that returns no results.

I was also thinking about simply negating the line using an `if` statement to decide whether the `userId` is the owner, but I don't know `s.UserId` until after the query is run.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using them in one where?

```
listUnpaged = listUnpaged
    .Where(s => s.User.UserName == user || !s.PostPrivate);
```

Comment: I don't think the initial check that the post is private is necessary. The logic can be simplified to: the user must match or the post must be public.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... It can't be simplified into one line because the `s.User.UserName` line is actually part of an `if`statement (checking if it's a specific user) and that is part of an even bigger query, that checks for other things like search queries and followed incidents/users and such. So, the postprivate comes outside the if statement when checking if it's a specific query for a user. Hopefully that makes sense? Can I see what you had originally?

Comment: So, imagine creating a list of all records... and you're going to negate any postprivate incidents, except to the owner... I may not have even needed to show you the second line in my example?

Comment: I was reading your edited comments and it looks like this works based off of what you wrote... `listUnpaged = listUnpaged.Where(s => (s.UserId == userId && s.PostPrivate) || !s.PostPrivate);` ... let me know if you have any other thoughts...

Comment: But the last version works also. You want the posts either public of the user must match (that will include the public and private)

Comment: Hi, yes, but again, my `.Where(s => s.User.UserName == user)` portion is inside an `if` statement when the type of query involves searching for incidents from a specific user. There are other portions that don't include searching for a specific user that are part of the same larger query that still need to exclude postprivate if it's `true` (unless the owner.) I could leave it like you said, but then have to consider it in other places, like followed incidents, search queries, etc. I'm trying to write one efficient line for `postprivate` that incorporates all query `if` types. Thanks again!!